# Example of a group of automorphisms of a non-abelian group that is cyclic

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I was reviewing my notes on Algebra when I found the following exercise:

> Prove that the group of automorphisms of a non-abelian group cannot be
>   cyclic

But the solution I have does it for inner automorphisms so I think that there is a mistake in the statement.

Can you give an example of a group of automorphisms of a non-abelian group that is cyclic or is the proposition above true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Recall:

- The group of inner automorphisms is a subgroup of the group of all automorphisms.
- All subgroups of a cyclic group are cyclic.

As a consequence, once you know that for a (type of) group the group of inner automorphisms is not cyclic, you also know that the group of all automorphisms is not cyclic for this (type of) group.